# Access site config in Docusaurus markdown doc

Tags: markdown, docusaurus

I'm trying to configure custom configuration variables according to the [docs](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/configuration#custom-configurations).

I added the following section in the `docusaurus.config.js`

```
  customFields: {
    foo: 'bar',
  },
```

And in my `.md` file I have:

```
---
id: fake-id
title: Test
---

# Title

import useDocusaurusContext from '@docusaurus/useDocusaurusContext';
const {siteConfig} = useDocusaurusContext();
<div>{siteConfig.customFields.foo}</div>;
```

The document does not render though. How can I access this variable in a doc markdown?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing your file from `.md` to `.mdx`? per [Docusaurus docs](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/react):

> While both .md and .mdx files are parsed using MDX, some of the syntax are treated slightly differently. For the most accurate parsing and better editor support, we recommend using the .mdx extension for files containing MDX syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There's a discussion of adding support for making `docusaurus.config.js` fields available in markdown: https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/395.

What should work is creating a file in `src`, e.g. `src/constants.js` with the following example content:

```
 export const customFields: {
    foo: 'bar',
  }
```

Then you can access the constant in a `.mdx`-file like this:

```
import {customFields} from '@site/src/constants';

This is the value: {customFields.foo}.
```